# Dynamically handling button views

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to dynamically handle the creation of onClick listeners for a 2d array of buttons. I do this by searching the resources for the button ID names however despite the buttons being initialised in XML correctly I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field button00 in class Landroid/widget/Button; (declaration of 'android.widget.Button' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex
```

The buttons are ID'd as follows: button00, button01, button02, button10...etc corresponding to their place in a 3x3 grid, can anyone point out why this is not working??

A 2d array of button objects is initialised beforehand:

```
private boolean zeroTurn = false;
private Button[][] boardButtons = new Button[3][3];
```

The following is in my onCreate for settting up the listeners:

```
for(int x = 0; x< this.boardButtons.length; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y< this.boardButtons[x].length; y++){
        try {
            String buttonname = new StringBuffer("button"+x+y).toString();
            boardButtons[x][y] = findViewById(getResId(buttonname,Button.class));
            boardButtons[x][y].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    Button clickedB = (Button) view;
                    Log.d("clickconfirm", "clicked!");
                    clickedB.setText(zeroTurn ? R.string.t_o:R.string.t_x);
                    clickedB.setEnabled(false);
                    zeroTurn = !zeroTurn;
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Fail", "automation failed");
        }


    }
}
```

The getResID function takes a string and class as an input and returns the ID of what i'm searching for:

```
 public static int getResId(String resName, Class<?> c) {

        try {
            Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resName);
            return idField.getInt(idField);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, I can confirm that the the button names are being formed correctly from the stacktrace as was implied by the error I supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
boardButtons[x][y] = findViewById(getResId(buttonname,Button.class));
```

```
public static int getResId(String resName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Replace these with:

```
boardButtons[x][y] = findViewById(getResId(this, buttonname));
```

```
public static int getResId(Context context, String buttonname) {
     context.getResources().getIdentifier(buttonname, "id", context.getPackageName());
}
```

This assumes that your code is being executed inside of an `Activity` (which seems likely since you called `findViewById()`). If not, you will need to pass a real `Context` instance to `getResId()` instead of just `this`.

Note that this will return `0` instead of `-1` if the resource id can't be found. If you *need* `-1` (which you shouldn't), then you can change it like this:

```
public static int getResId(Context context, String buttonname) {
     int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(buttonname, "id", context.getPackageName());
     return (id == 0) ? -1 : id;
}
```

Comment: Your code solved my issue beautifully, but I'm afraid I'm rather new to android specific programming, can you explain in more detail why you decided to use `Context` instead of passing the class?

Comment: @AdrianCoutsoftides You're trying to go from e.g. `"button12"` to `R.id.button12`. That id is a `static final` constant inside the `id` class inside `R.java`. It is _not_ a part of the `Button` class. And the mechanism to turn a `String` into a resource identifier is the `Resources.getIdentifier()` method, which is just something you learn with time.